# Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, require

Plz help me, I'm using the following code:

index.js:

```
var $ =  require('./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min');
var _ = require('./node_modules/underscore/underscore-min');
var Backbone = require('./node_modules/backbone/backbone-min');
require('./model/models');

run();

function run(){
    var session = new ****.***.Models.CustomerSession();
    session.save({
        "authenticators": ["********","****"]
    }).always(function(xhr){
        do_something...
    });
}
```

models.js:

```
**** = {};
****.*** = {};
****.***.Models = {};

var _ = require('../node_modules/underscore/underscore-min');
var Backbone = require('../node_modules/backbone/backbone-min');

/////////////MODELS/////////////

****.***.Models.CustomerSession = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot : 'https://*****.****.com/api/***/customer_session/'
});

****.***.Models.Transaction = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot : 'https://*****.****.com/api/***/transaction/'
});

****.***.Models.FaultType = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot : 'https://*****.****.com/api/***/fault_type/'
});

****.***.Models.FaultTypeSet = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot : 'https://*****.****.com/api/***/fault_type/'
});

****.***.Models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot : 'https://*****.****.com/api/***/task/'
});
///////////////////////////////
```

And get the following ERROR: "Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined"...
This is all the code in the project except the node_modules libraries...
I think that backbone don't recognize the $ sign, but I'm not sure and don't know what to do with the problem... 
Plz help me...

Here is the error log as I see it:

```
c:\ce\test_script\node_modules\backbone\backbone-min.js:1
h:"PATCH","delete":"DELETE",read:"GET"};e.ajax=function(){return e.$.ajax.appl
                                                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined
at Object.e.ajax (c:\ce\test_script\node_modules\backbone\backbone-min.js:1:14801)
at e.sync (c:\ce\test_script\node_modules\backbone\backbone-min.js:1:14518)
at i.extend.sync (c:\ce\test_script\node_modules\backbone\backbone-min.js:1:3208)
at i.extend.save (c:\ce\test_script\node_modules\backbone\backbone-min.js:1:5716)
at run (c:\ce\test_script\index.js:14:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\ce\test_script\index.js:10:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)

Process finished with exit code 8
```

Here is the error log when using backbone instead of backbone-min:

```
c:\ce\test_script\node_modules\backbone\backbone.js:1209
return Backbone.$.ajax.apply(Backbone.$, arguments);
                 ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined
at Object.Backbone.ajax (c:\ce\test_script\node_modules\backbone\backbone.js:1209:22)
at Backbone.sync (c:\ce\test_script\node_modules\backbone\backbone.js:1188:38)
at _.extend.sync (c:\ce\test_script\node_modules\backbone\backbone.js:286:28)
at _.extend.save (c:\ce\test_script\node_modules\backbone\backbone.js:493:18)
at run (c:\ce\test_script\index.js:17:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\ce\test_script\index.js:10:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)

Process finished with exit code 8
```

Comment: In order for us to help you, we need more information on the error. Does it say in which file the error occured, on which line, etc. Give us as much information as possible

Comment: The jQuery library does not seem to be loaded. May be you need to `require` it in models.js too.

Comment: add `var $ =  require('./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min');` to the second file and you be golden

Comment: Thanks guys but it still not working

Comment: You may need to pass in jquery or define where jquery is for require especially if this is node side.  There is some scoping there such that var $ may not be on global.

Comment: Can you explain yourself?

Comment: for debug purposes don't use the minified version of backbone, please replace the backbone.min.js with regular source code and then post your report

Comment: I posted the error log with backbone instead of backbone-min...

Comment: I think that the problem is that requier('jquery') not working, I figured it when I tried to do this : console.log($); and got this:  [Function]...  but I don't know how to solve this problem...

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @RobertLevy You should do: `Backbone.$ = $` to define jQuery dependency. However, ajax won't work in node.js, as it doesn't have the `XMLHttpRequest` object. You'd need a polyfill for that (like [najax](https://github.com/najaxjs/najax)).

Answer (score 2):

This was buried in the comments above, but I was having the same problem and setting

`Backbone.$ = $`

fixed the issue for me